# How can I find out when was a certain number input? C

Tags: c

I need to make a program in which I must scanf integers, and they must be between 1 and 30, and when some number is input for a second time, I must printf what number is it and what was his position of input.

For example, if scanf'd numbers are 1 3 5 7 3, program must printf "Number 3 was 2nd scanned number".

The thing that bugs me is how to find out what was the position of the input number, how to find out that 3 was input before on 2nd position.

And I must make this program only with stdio.h.

Comment: Show your attempt to code this.

Comment: I deleted the code already, I will try to explain what I was doing, and if you want I can rewrite the code I did before. So I made an array of 30 ints, each int representing a number between 1 and 30, then in for loop scanf'ing numbers, and the counter of for loop (1,2,3...) would be saved into array position of that number and then another for loop inside that one that would check if the newly scanned number was already scanned, and then the getting the number that was saved in that particular array position. But that didn't work. I can close and reopen the question with the code if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the numbers you read in an array, like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int vet[10000]; // assuming you wont enter more than 10000 numbers
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        scanf ("%d", &vet[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (vet[i] == vet[j]) {
                printf ("Number %d was %dth scanned number", vet[i], j+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Another approach (which is a lot better, but only possible because the input is limited), is to store in an array the position where the number was first found, and -1 if it was not found yet, like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int vet[31];
    int aux, counter;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
        vet[i] = -1; //not found yet
    counter = 1;
    while (1) {
        scanf ("%d", &aux);
        if (aux < 1 || aux > 30) { //check for wrong input
            continue;
        }
        if (vet[aux] == -1) {
            vet[aux] = counter;
        }
        else {
            printf ("Number %d was %dth scanned number", aux, vet[aux]);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your first code, although modified a bit, worked for me. Didn't try 2nd code, but will try.

Comment: Generally the first code is very bad because it allocates memory on the stack immediately when it is not needed. the second approach is much better. you should avoid the first solution

Comment: Sure, but it doesnt work if the input is not limited or if its a float, for example.

Comment: Also, if the input is limited but the range is bigger than the expected number of integers received, the first approach is recomended.

Comment: @ForeverStudent The thing is, the first code is not bad, but I think you misunderstood something. I needed an array of 30 ints, where every int from 0-30 would represent one number, and when a number outside that interval was input, the program would ask you to input the number again, as it's an invalid number, guess I left that out. So I tweaked your program to have an array of 30 so it takes the same amount of memory as the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep an array of 30 position that keeps track of the first index that every number was entered. 
Remember that arrays start with index 0. 
this program will run indefinitely until you press `ctrl + C`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    int indexOfFirstOccurrence[30];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<30;++i)indexOfFirstOccurrence[i]=0;
    int counter=1;
    int input;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("please enter input #%d:  ",counter);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        //error checking would be advised

        if(indexOfFirstOccurrence[input-1]==0)indexOfFirstOccurrence[input-1]=counter;
        printf("the first time %d was entered was at iteration %d \n",input, indexOfFirstOccurrence[input-1]);
        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```